# Consistent of the two definitions of L-moments

Tags: st.statistics

I don't know how to prove that the definition

\begin{equation}
    \lambda_r = \frac{1}{r} \sum_{j=0}^{r-1} (-1)^j {r - 1 \choose j} E[X_{r-j:r}]
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
    E[X_{r:n}] = \frac{n!}{(r - 1)! \: (n - r)!} \int_{0}^{1} x(u) \: u^{r-1} \:(1-u)^{n-r} \: du
\end{equation}

is consistent with

\begin{equation}
    \lambda_r =  \int_{0}^{1} x(u) P^*_{r-1}(u) du
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
    P^*_r(u) = \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} p^*_{r-1,k} u^k,
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
    p^*_{r,k} = (-1)^{r-k} {r \choose k} {r + k \choose k} = \frac{(-1)^{r-k} (r + k)!}{(k!)^2 (r - k)!}
\end{equation}

The indication that gives me is "Substituting the definition of the expectation of an order statistic in the first formula, expanding the binomials in $u$ and summing the coefficients of each power of $u$". The indication is from Hosking (1990) - https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1990.tb01775.x

Thanks

Comment: Although you have an answer, "The indication that gives me" suggests this is a homework problem or other exercise, in which case it doesn't belong here.

Comment: I agree with LSpice. If it's from a paper then it is maybe appropriate for MathOverflow but please add citation.

Comment: I'm new here and I don't really know how this works.  it is an indication given in an article to go from one formula to another

Comment: @rma then it would appreciated and helpful if you could also mention or cite the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{equation}
    EX_{r-j:r}=\frac{r!}{(r-j-1)!\,j!} \int_0^1 du\,x(u)\,u^{r-j-1}\,(1-u)^j \\ 
    =r\binom{r-1}j \int_0^1 du\,x(u)\,u^{r-j-1}\,(1-u)^j
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    (1-u)^j=\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^i \binom ji u^i. 
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
    \lambda_r=\int_0^1 du\,x(u)\,p_r(u),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    p_r(u):=\sum_{j=0}^{r-1} (-1)^j \binom{r-1}j^2 u^{r-j-1}\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^i \binom ji u^i
    =\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} p_{r,k}u^k,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    p_{r,k}:=(-1)^{r-1-k}\sum_{j=r-1-k}^{r-1} \binom{r-1}j^2 \binom j{r-k-1}
    =\frac{(-1)^{k+r-1} (k+r-1)!}{(k!)^2 (r-k-1)!}, 
\end{equation}
as desired.
The latter equality (which I obtained with Mathematica's help) can be obtained by using [Vol. 1 (in Russian), Formula 4.2.9.5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07282HHH2):
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2 \binom k{n-m}=\binom nm \binom{n+m}m \tag{1}
\end{equation}
with $r-1,k$ in place of $n,m$, respectively. (This book is available [online](https://ru.b-ok2.org/book/2889120/e35933).)

Actually, it is easy to see why (1) is true. Indeed,
\begin{equation}
    \binom nk^2 \binom k{n-m}=\binom nm \binom nk \binom m{n-k}
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{align}
    \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2 \binom k{n-m}
    &   =\binom nm \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \binom m{n-k}\\
    &=\binom nm \binom{n+m}n 
        =\binom nm \binom{n+m}m. 
\end{align}

Comment: Hello, first, thanks for answering.

I just edited my question to fix the two bugs that were there. The indices were not good, they were only up to r-1. I have the same as you, but I don't see how you build $p_ {r, k}$

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: @rma : I am not sure what you mean by "build". However, I have added details on $p_{r,k}$.

Comment: I meant the last equality in your definition of $P_r (u)$. I don't understand how you got the index k and put $u^k$.

I had come to the same as you, well, except for the final equalities of the combinatorial numbers. I wouldn't have seen that in a thousand years.

(And finally, forgive my English, it is very bad and I use the google translator)

Comment: @rma : I just use $u^{r-j-1} u^i=u^k$ for $k:=r-j-1+i$, noting that, for each $j$, the condition $0\le i\le j$ is equivalent to $r-j-1\le k\le r-1$.

Comment: Thansk for all!!!