# Bijective proof of a combinatorial identity: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2 \binom k{n-m}=\binom nm \binom{n+m}m$

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, bijective-combinatorics

Identity
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2 \binom k{n-m}=\binom nm \binom{n+m}m \tag{1}
\end{equation}
was used in an [answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365141/consistent-of-the-two-definitions-of-l-moments/365154#365154). As shown in that answer, (1) easily reduces to
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \binom m{n-k}=\binom{n+m}n,  \tag{2}
\end{align}
which latter admits an obvious [bijective proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_proof#:%7E:text=In%20combinatorics%2C%20bijective%20proof%20is,A%7C%20%3D%20%7CB%7C.).

**Question:** Is there a bijective proof of the original identity (1), without the reduction to (2)?

A possibly relevant reference is to [automated search for bijective proofs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288051/automated-search-for-bijective-proofs).

Comment: First apply the trinomial revision formula (and symmetry of binomial coefficients) to get $\dbinom{n}{k}\dbinom{k}{n-m} = \dbinom{n}{m} \dbinom{m}{k-n+m}$. This lets you factor out $\dbinom{n}{m}$, and the sum turns into an easy Vandermonde convolution. All the steps can be made bijective, since they just use trinomial revision (in the case when everything is a nonnegative integer), symmetry of binomial coefficients and Vandermonde convolution. Thus you get a bijective proof by pasting together these bijections.

Comment: I have tried to put this identity into some search engines, specifically [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%5Cbinom%20nk%5E2%20%5Cbinom%20k%7Bn-m%7D%3D%5Cbinom%20nm%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%2Bm%7Dm%24&p=1) and [SearchOnMath](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%5Cbinom%20nk%5E2%20%5Cbinom%20k%7Bn-m%7D%3D%5Cbinom%20nm%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%2Bm%7Dm%24&p=1). There is this post, where the answer gives a combinatorial proof: [Some binomial coefficient identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1424724)

Comment: [Proving $\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}^2 \binom{m}{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3168078) The answers there point out that this is a special case of $\sum_{k\ge0}\binom ak\binom bk\binom kc=\binom ac\binom{a+b-c}a$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg : Thank you for your comment, which actually answers the question. Your identity is the same I used in the linked answer to reduce (1) to (2). However, I did not realize that it is an instance of the trinomial revision (and I did not even know that term, "trinomial revision").

Comment: @MartinSleziak : Thank you for your comments, one providing another bijective proof and the other providing a generalization of the identity. Also, I think you previously suggested this valuable resource, approach0, and I actually bookmarked it, but then forgot about it.